What is involved for the BIOS to populate the ACPI tables in terms of system fans?
i recently had to flash my bios with a programmer using basically a blank bios firmware update that didnt contain any of my laptop’s info. it went successfully but one of the problems i still have is that the system fans are non functional. the fans or cooling devices according to the acpi spec are not even in the acpi tables. almost everything other piece of hardware is in the acpi except for thermal relationships and cooling devices. im pretty sure populating them by hand is beyond me.
i have flashed my bios again with my programmer and i added a bunch of data strings to the dmi in the bios but im still not seeing any cooling devices.
i was wondering if anyone could elucidate on what info is required by the bios, maybe in terms of dmi strings or the dmi in general or whatever, to add system fans or cooling devices to the acpi tables and/or maybe describe how the whole process goes?
ive tried alot of things but nothing…load defaults, windows driver stuff… my last option i am going to try is to reflash my bios normally through lenovo’s bios update exe. the exe doesnt override any dmi strings and i was hoping that the flash process would kick start the bios seeing the fans and repopulate everything.
ive also tried looking at the dmi strings in various bios files i found on the internet but none of them had anything related to fans or cooling devices as far as i can tell.
any advice is greatly appreciated.
